# Can't remove black transition effect when changing video src using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, video

Wondering if anyone can assist with my Angular HTML video issues.

I am trying to run multiple video files consecutively in full screen one after the other (like a playlist) in the same `<video>` element by updating the `ng-src=""` using AngularJS. Whilst I seem to have had some luck getting these videos to play, it is causing a black transition delay (milliseconds) between each video file as it loads the new source.  I can't seem for the life of me to be able to remove this unwanted transition effect. The client wants the movie files to play seamlessly in full screen one after the other without any black screening.

I have tried updating the source using Javascript in the controller and using the `video.pause()` and `video.load()` options.  I have tried `Videogular` and `ng-video` using the playlist option but I get the same result.  I have tried using `uib-carousel` but it doesn't want to slide to the next video (seems unsupported) and I have even tried running two `<video>` elements on the DOM and trying to switch their `z-index` and `visibility` flags but that won't play the second movie at all when the first one disappears (seems to work if I run both videos side by side, but not in full screen)

I'm not sure if this is a browser related problem or if I'm using the wrong approach, or if it can even be done?  The ONLY possible example that comes close is [MDBootstrap Video Carousel](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/extended/video-carousel/) but that doesn't seem to support AngularJS.

** Update **

Sorry, I should also note that these videos should all play automatically at fullscreen, one after the other without any user intervention.

Comment: I am completely unfamiliar with the limitations of the HTML video player, but I imagine you're at the mercy of the browser implementation. If opacity is supported, you could absolutely position multiple video elements on top of each other and transition the opacities between them much like a carousel. Double check the videos you are playing don't contain the black slate you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks @MarkClark. The videos don't contain the black slate, they are continuous movie files that all join together seamlessly.  I have tried stacking the video elements on top of each other and using the `element.style.visibility = 'hidden';` call to make the top one disappear, however, the underlaying video remains a complete black screen (doesn't seem to play at all), unless I run both videos side by side.

Comment: Instead of using hidden, what about opacity? I wouldn't be surprised if certain browsers don't play a video in a hidden element to prevent unstoppable/malicious media. I would also only hide the video as it goes out, not the new one starting. The video taking its place should probably always be visible and at 100% opacity to prevent the browser from seeing it as hidden. So place the upcoming video underneath the outgoing one, hiding or fading the outgoing video should 'reveal' the next one.